# How do you add custom taxonomy capabilities exactly?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, capabilities

I can't see to get it. The capabilities fail to appear when using plugins like "Capability Manager" or "Members" to view a list of available capabilities.

This is the code I'm attempting to use:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_taxonomy_spot_tag' );

function register_taxonomy_spot_tag() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( 'Spot Tags', 'spot tag' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Spot Tag', 'spot tag' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search Spot Tags', 'spot tag' ),
        'popular_items' => _x( 'Popular Spot Tags', 'spot tag' ),
        'all_items' => _x( 'All Spot Tags', 'spot tag' ),
        'parent_item' => _x( 'Parent Spot Tag', 'spot tag' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Spot Tag:', 'spot tag' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Spot Tag', 'spot tag' ),
        'update_item' => _x( 'Update Spot Tag', 'spot tag' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Spot Tag', 'spot tag' ),
        'new_item_name' => _x( 'New Spot Tag Name', 'spot tag' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => _x( 'Separate spot tags with commas', 'spot tag' ),
        'add_or_remove_items' => _x( 'Add or remove spot tags', 'spot tag' ),
        'choose_from_most_used' => _x( 'Choose from the most used spot tags', 'spot tag' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Spot Tags', 'spot tag' ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_tagcloud' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,

        'rewrite' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'capabilities' => array(
            'manage_terms' => 'manage_spot_tags',
            'edit_terms' => 'edit_spot_tags',
            'delete_terms' => 'delete_spot_tags',
            'assign_terms' => 'assign_spot_tags'
        )
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'spot_tag', array('spot'), $args );
}
```

I generated the above code with this tool:
http://themergency.com/generators/wordpress-custom-taxonomy/

Answer (score 1):

Try using add_cap  .... [**adding new capability**](http://www.garyc40.com/2010/04/ultimate-guide-to-roles-and-capabilities/#add-capability) and creating the capability first in functions.php, i cant locate anything that says capabilities can be created in registering a taxonomy, but you can certainly assign them there..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already saw that. The code I used in the example was generated at http://themergency.com/generators/wordpress-custom-taxonomy/. It seems to work very nicely for adding post types (capabilities are added automatically). But I guess that's not the case with taxonomies (as the site obviously claims with the automatic generator).

Comment: I see if I can create the capability first and see what happens...

Answer (score -2):

This is really old, but number uno hit on my google search, I found the anwser to be.

You don't need to pre add the capabilities, just add ", 'map_meta_cap' => true" to you above code like so

```
$args = array( 
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_tagcloud' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,

    'rewrite' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'capabilities' => array(
        'manage_terms' => 'manage_spot_tags',
        'edit_terms' => 'edit_spot_tags',
        'delete_terms' => 'delete_spot_tags',
        'assign_terms' => 'assign_spot_tags'
    ), 
    'map_meta_cap' => true
);
```

This will make it add the capabilities seamlessly

Comment: Hi, thanks for contributing but according to the developer docs https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/ , `register_taxonomy` doesn't have a `map_meta_cap` argument.  `register_post_type` does, but its purpose is not to make third party plugins show checkboxes for capabilities, but to toggle which base capabilities are used to construct meta capabilities such as `edit_post`.